# Error found when loading /home/username/.profile

Tags: boot

getting the following error when rebooting:

```
Error found when loading /home/username/.profile:

/home/username/.profile:line 28: /bin/brew: No such File or directory
/home/username/.profile:line 29: /bin/brew: No such File or directory

As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
You should fix this problem as soon as feasible.
```

here is my system info:

```
mrpalmer@mrpalmer-MacBookAir:~$ uname -a
Linux mrpalmer-MacBookAir 5.11.0-41-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 10 10:20:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

not sure what other information would be helpful. I just installed Ubuntu on this computer a few days ago. any help is appreciated

Comment: You have an error in line 28 and 29 in your .profie ... Please update your question with the content of that file, Or work out why /bin/brew doesn't exist, or what the correct path is.